# How test if a particular line of JavaScript code is supported by Browser

Tags: javascript

Could anybody suggest how can I test if a particular line of JavaScript code is supported by Browser or not. If not how can I handle it? As I am learning JavaScript it would be a great help to know.

Comment: have a look at http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Check the `window` object for existence of the API you want

Comment: Please post the specific code you're asking about.  The techniques vary depending upon what it is.

Comment: There's a site I ran across a few weeks ago where you paste in JS and it detects potential browse compatibility issues, but I'm too lazy to track it down right now. I tried it and it seemed to be moderately useful.

Comment: More context information is needed. Do you want to take any arbitrary line of JS code and find out whether it can be executed in the browser? I.g. `i++` or `new Map()`? Or do you want to conditionally execute code in your own module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either: 1) Assume that the code works, and handle the cases where it doesn't:

```
try{
   // ...
}catch(e){
   // an error occurred
}
```

Or 2) check if the function it relies on exists, and then use it:

```
if(window.yourfunction){
   // The function is present in the global scope
}else{
   // Not available, try alternatives?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This would seem to be the perfect time to use `try`/`catch`:

```js
    try {
        // your JavaScript here
        document.executeSomeUnknownFunction();
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("There was an error: " + error);
    }

console.log("...but nothing broke");
```

Or, alternatively, assuming it's a method of an Object you're testing for (for example `querySelectorAll()`):

```js
if ('querySelectorAll' in document) {
  console.log("We support  'document.querySelectorAll()'");
 }
```

References:

- [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).
- [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

Comment: Might be that something does not work, but there is no exception.

Comment: True, but it depends what 'that' might be; and given the limited information in the question it's hard to account for possibilities I can't anticipate.

Comment: That's right. This question can most likely not be answered in a general way. Like @jfriend00 said in the comments: The techniques vary depending upon what it is.

Comment: BTW: console.log might also not supported ;-)

Comment: @Thilo: that would be entertainingly ironic... :D

Comment: Thank you @David Thomas for the suggestion.